# Название внешней отделки двери

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как назвается это углубление на двери? Вырез, резьба?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Периметр вашей двери - это каркас, рама; внутренняя часть - филенка; углубление - это паз. Данная дверь может являеться как реально филенчатой, так и имитацией таковой. Филенка - доска или фанера, вставленная в раму. Данное углубление является декоративным технологическим пазом.